# SharedIntent in an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share, android-alertdialog

I want to make an `AlertDialog` with three buttons. Two of them work good but not the third one. The last button is a `SharedIntent` and shares the score of the user. I really don't know what causes the crash so here is my code:

```
alert.setNeutralButton("Partager", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "text to share";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));                
    }
});
```

Comment: Post logcat in your post

Comment: Are you sure the code crashes in this method?

Comment: Yes I'm sure the app works well until I try to share.

I'm using the emulator so it always crashes when the app tries to connect to the Internet : the error on the LogCat is the AndroidRuntimeException but I also tried on a phone and it crashes and I can't tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was from the last line of the code, so here's the right code :

```
alert.setNeutralButton("Partager", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "text to share";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    MyActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));                
  }
});
```

And replace "MyActivity" by yours.